# Use popen or ShellExecute to programmatically get winget output from command prompt, NOT working

Tags: command, popen, shellexecute, winget

First, I installed winget-cli and open a command prompt on the device, I can get the winget version.

see image1 on [https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/22248019/127574830-3f01c414-09c2-4a29-bbe6-60a62ea49b18.png][1]

The device also installed our app with feature which can programmatically get the output from command prompt. Like when you input "ipconfig" from our app, you can get the device's ip address information. But when I input "winget -v", only return me "'winget' is not recognized as an internal or external command". The following picture show the output in our app. You can see the commands input would get proper outputs except winget command

see image 2 on [https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/22248019/127573134-9b78ad99-9c0b-4671-b146-62c60ef74866.png][2]

The piece of code look like this :

```
char sBuffer[256];
while (fgets(sBuffer, sizeof(sBuffer) - 1, pipe) != NULL) {
        cout << "winget version result:" + sBuffer;
}

Does anyone know why this not working


  [1]: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/22248019/127574830-3f01c414-09c2-4a29-bbe6-60a62ea49b18.png
  [2]: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/22248019/127573134-9b78ad99-9c0b-4671-b146-62c60ef74866.png
```

Answer (score 0):

The error appears to be related to the context the app is running under. The Windows Package Manager is delivered via the App Installer from the Microsoft Store. MSIX packages are registered for a user, not the system. If the application code is running under the registered user context and the error still persists, take a look at the [troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/tree/master/doc/troubleshooting).